# Permission denied - /Users/<user>/Library/Logs/Homebrew/flann when using brew

Tags: macos, homebrew, permission-denied

I wanted to install pcl by `brew` on OSX.

```
$ brew install pcl
==> Installing pcl from homebrew/science
==> Installing dependencies for homebrew/science/pcl: flann, cminpack, qh
==> Installing homebrew/science/pcl dependency: flann
==> Downloading http://people.cs.ubc.ca/~mariusm/uploads/FLANN/flann-1.8.4-src.z
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/flann-1.8.4.zip
==> cmake .. -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE=-DNDEBUG -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE=-DNDEBUG
Error: Permission denied - /Users/xxh/Library/Logs/Homebrew/flann
```

Commend `cmake` is fine.

I tried `sudo brew install pcl`. It's not work.

How to fix it?

Comment: So what are the perms on that directory?  What about the intermediate directories?  This is basic user-level stuff.

Comment: @trojanfoe it's auto prosessed.I don't know how to set the the intermediate directories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to fix the rights?

```
$ chmod -R 755 ~/Library/Logs/Homebrew
```

Should fix this issue and you could retry the installation...

Comment: lt's `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Users/<user name>/Library/Logs/Homebrew`.
`brew doctor` can see